# SQL - Snowflake - Inner Join not working as expected

Tags: sql, inner-join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table `ADS` in snowflake like so (data is being inserted each day), note there are duplicates entries on rows 3 and 4:

| ID | REPORT_DATE | CLICKS | IMPRESSIONS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 01 | 20 | 400 |
| 1 | Jan 02 | 25 | 600 |
| 1 | Jan 03 | 80 | 900 |
| 1 | Jan 03 | 80 | 900 |
| 2 | Jan 01 | 30 | 500 |
| 2 | Jan 02 | 55 | 650 |
| 2 | Jan 03 | 90 | 950 |

I want to select all entries based on `ID` with the max `REPORT_DATE` - essentially I want to know the latest number of `CLICKS` and `IMPRESSIONS` for each `ID`:

| ID | REPORT_DATE | CLICKS | IMPRESSIONS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 03 | 80 | 900 |
| 2 | Jan 03 | 90 | 950 |

This query successfully gives me the max `DATE` for each `ID`:

```sql
SELECT
  MAX(REPORT_DATE),
  ID
FROM ADS
GROUP BY 
  ID;
```

Result:

| ID | MAX(REPORT_DATE) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 03 |
| 2 | Jan 03 |

However, when I try to conduct an inner join, duplicates arise:

```sql
SELECT 
  a.ID,
  a.REPORT_DATE,
  a.CLICKS,
  a.IMPRESSIONS
FROM ADS a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    MAX(REPORT_DATE),
    ID
  FROM ADS
  GROUP BY 
      ID
) b 
ON a.ID = b.ID
AND a.REPORT_DATE = b.REPORT_DATE;
```

Result:

| ID | REPORT_DATE | CLICKS | IMPRESSIONS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 03 | 80 | 900 |
| 1 | Jan 03 | 80 | 900 |
| 2 | Jan 03 | 90 | 950 |

How can I construct my query to remove these duplicates?

Comment: Thanks such detail information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `QUALIFY` and `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT a.ID,a.REPORT_DATE,a.CLICKS,a.IMPRESSIONS
FROM ADS a
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY REPORT_DATE DESC) = 1;
```

Please note that `ORDER BY REPORT_DATE` is not stable(in case of a tie). I would suggest adding another column for sorting that is the tuple is always unique.

If the rows that have a tie are the same it actually is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks - as I mentioned in a different comment, the column `ROW` does not exist in my table - I'll clarify this in my question.

Comment: @Daniel Then in case of a tie, any arbitrary row is choosen. In provided case it does not really matter as they are essentialy the same.

Comment: That should be fine - as I am new to SQL, can you please just give some background on how this last line of the query works?

Comment: QUALIFY is like a filter clause for windowed function. ROW_NUMBER create a numbering per each ID sorting the input based on REPORT_DATE descending. Then the one that got 1 are selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` window function:

```
select id, report_date, clicks, impresions from
(
 select id, report_date, clicks, impresions, row_number()over(partition by id order 
 by report_date desc) rnk from ADs
)t
where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks - I will clarify that the column `ROW` does not exist in my table and that the latest entry in the table is not necessarily the row that I need.

Comment: I removed my second answer. Misunderstood your data. Then row_number() window function will do the work. And thanks again for asking question with such detail and clean information. Best wishes.